# Javafx stage resizeable false and maximized true hides the taskbar

Tags: java, javafx-8

In my JavaFX FXML application when I set resizable to false and maximized to true the window becomes maximized but the taskbar gets hidden. I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 on Windows 7 64 Bit with JDK 1.8.60

In Netbeans I followed the steps to create a new JavaFX FXML application. To the default code generated I added the following two lines in the start function.

```
stage.setResizable(false);
stage.setMaximized(true);
```

Hence the final start function is as below

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().
        getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.setMaximized(true);
    stage.show();
}
```

Now when I run the application the window is maximized, title bar is visible but the task bar is not visible. How should I fix this i.e. make the task bar visible?

Comment: I can not reproduce this - your code properly **maximizes** the window, with the title buttons still shown. Only when I replace  `stage.setMaximized(true);` with `stage.setFullScreen(true);`, the window is properly shown **fullscreen**, without title buttons and with a note window to press `ESC` to close full screen mode. Do you have anything unusual in your `.fxml` file? Ideally post a [mcve] which we can directly drop into `javac` to reproduce the issue.

Comment: In Netbeans I followed the steps to create a new application and to the default code generated I added the resizable and maximized code.

Comment: So, with the above code, you get a notification like "Press ESC to close fullscreen mode", and the maximized window does **not** contain a title bar with the usual buttons for close and minimize? Which window system on which operating system are you using, and what is your exact JDK version?

Comment: I am able to see the title bar, window is maximized but not able to see taskbar. I am using JDK 1.8.60

Answer (score 6):

@JC997 Has a great answer but I want to refine.

While using setWidth and setHeight you do not preventing your user from resizing the whole window. Combining *setResizeable(false)* with the following code won't help in that case neither.

You should apply **Min** and **Max** values to actually achieve what you are looking for, use this

```
Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
stage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMinX());
stage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMinY());

stage.setMaxWidth(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth());
stage.setMinWidth(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth());

stage.setMaxHeight(primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());
stage.setMinHeight(primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want you're stage not resizable and maximized, with the taskbar visible, you can use this code I think:

```
Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
stage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMinX());
stage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMinY());
stage.setWidth(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth());
stage.setHeight(primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());
```

What this does, is looking for the screen boundaries and it takes the taskbar into account.